# Can I add an "open with" option to Photo app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, photo

Can I add my application to the list of options in the built-in Photo app?
(Email Photo, MMS, Assign to Contact, Use as Wallpaper, Use my custom app)

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no published method to do this.